# Field with Rich Text using <font face="font name">

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am taking advantage of a rich text field to format a textbox with multiple colors and fonts.  I can use any font as long as there is no space in the font name.  Example, "impact" font works fine but "Segoe MDL2 Assets" will not work.  I used the '' in the place of " and I still have problems.  Is there any way to call the Segoe MDL2 Assets font to address this issue?

```
SELECT "<font face=''Segoe MDL2 Assets'' color=#557091>" & [ObjectGlyph] & "</font> " & [ObjectName] & IIf(IsNull([Remark]),"","  <font face=''Segoe MDL2 Assets'' color=#FFFFFF>(" & [Remark] & ")</font>") AS ListName, qryNexusUnion.*
FROM qryNexusUnion
ORDER BY qryNexusUnion.SortGroup, qryNexusUnion.ObjectCode, qryNexusUnion.ObjectName;
```

Comment: You probably have tried this too, but I would guess a single quote would work. `SELECT "<font face='Segoe MDL2 Assets' etc`

Comment: Oh and: what does *will not work* mean? Do you get an error, or is the default font used?

Comment: Possible crude workaround: copy (duplicate) the font file, rename without spaces, install in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Apostrophe (aka single quote) does not work - singled or doubled.

Use doubled quotes:

`SELECT "... face=""Segoe MDL2 Assets"" ..." AS ListName`

or apostrophes for the outer delimiters and embedded singled quotes (not doubled single quote aka apostrophe):

`SELECT '... face="Segoe MDL2 Assets" ...' AS ListName`